# Electrons produced in water by ionizing radiation vs. electrons due to electrostatic charge: are they equally reactive?

Tags: electrostatics, radiation, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, ions

It is known that one of the things generated in water or aqueous solutions by the ionizing radiations are free electrons that quickly become "hydrated" or "aqueous electrons" (see for example [this](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-physchem-052516-050816) or [this](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.ns.15.120165.001013))

And it is said that this is a chemically reactive species (reducing agent). Does it hold also for the electrons accumulated in the body when it is charged by static electricity? If not, why not?

Comment: Why do you think there are noticeable amounts of electrons accumulated in the body due to static electricity?

Comment: I think the amount of electrons must be noticeable because the amount of charge is noticeable, since the electrostatic effects are very evident for example in the experiences with van-de-Graaf generators (hair raising, etc) or in everyday life (occasional sparks when we get out of the car or when using some type of clothing, etc). In contrast, the irradiation using high energy electrons (e.g. radiation therapy in a linear accelerator) does not cause noticeable electrostatic effects unless the radiation dose is extremely high (never done with patients, only phantoms).

Comment: After doing some numbers I think the amount of charge (ions) produced by ionizing radiation can be in the order or millicoulombs per kg. The amount of positive and negative charge is the same, so from the macroscopic point of view the body is still neutral. What could be the charge in an electrostatic charging like the ones above?

Comment: [Crossposted in chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158308/hydrated-electrons-produced-by-radiation-vs-electrons-from-electrostatic-charge)